# How Can I Kill a Enderman and Not Lose 5-6 Hearts?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I better hunt Endermen?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41693/how-can-i-better-hunt-endermen)

There is a problem that I face, how can I kill a enderman and not lose something like 4-6 hearts?

Also, does a enderman have more protection and/or more attack if they're holding a item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method is to build a roof with a 2 block space underneath it.  He needs a 3 block space to walk, but you only need 2.  You have a longer reach than the Enderman, meaning you can hit him while under the roof, but he can't hit you.

Stand under the roof, look at an Enderman, then look away to draw him in, and then hit him with the pointy end.

Comment: What do you mean by pointy end?

Comment: I prefer the pointy end 99% of the time.

Comment: @JefreyLin: It's a reference to Game of Thrones.  It means a sword.

Comment: Thanks! ;-)        I was just looking at on of your other conversations about the breaking blocks on adventure mode!